# "image not found" Error while using Custom FrameWork

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I created my own framework for one of my cocoa application. I added that framework to my project and called a method from that framework. When I tried to run my application it crashed:

**Crash Log:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MMP.framework/Versions/A/MMP
  Referenced from: /Users/Midhun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MMPTest-ccvjtgedqkcftchapjehhwjbaqdq/Build/Products/Debug/MMPTest.app/Contents/MacOS/MMPTest
  Reason: image not found
```

### What I have done:

#### FrameWork:

- I added my header file in public section

[image: Public Header]

- I added the paths of Deployment and `Linking` like:

[image: Paths]

- I build the project and I got my framework ready (Pretty cool till here).

#### Project:

- I added that framework to `FrameWorks` folder under my Project's root directory.
- I added the framework under `Link Binary With Libraries` Section
- I changed the path of Linking like:
  [image: Changed Path]

**Platform Details:**

```
Xcode: 4.6.2
OS X : 10.8
```

**What I have tried (After the crash)**

- When I get this issue, I checked with `otool`. It shows the paths like:

[image: otool]

- I followed this link: [A Visual Guide to Creating an Embeddable Framework for Mac OSX](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/12/28/a-visual-guide-to-creating-an-embeddable-framework-for-mac-osx)

But I couldn't fix the issue, yet. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798623/xcode-dynamic-library-linking-how-to-properly-set-run-paths-search-paths-and

Comment: @trojanfoe: No I tried that first, it not worked for me. That's why I asked this question :)

Comment: But you didn't follow the accepted answer's advise of leaving *install name* to its default value.

Comment: @trojanfoe: if we change the Installation directory and Run Path It'll automatically change the install name (Please check my image: The Install name is default, XCode shows changed one in bold and default value in normal font)

Comment: Do you know where the app and framework are finally being written to?  I would have thought an xcode workspace would be a better option for this kind of thing.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Is any way to copy my framework to my binary's install folder (Xcode derived data folder) ?

Comment: Is very simple. Only check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found#30979099

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set framework installation directory to `@executable_path/../Frameworks`

[image]

Now add copy files in your build phase, set destination to   `Frameworks`. click on your **target**, then on **Editor** (menu bar) --> **Add build phase** --> **Add Copy Files Build Phase**

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Add Copy Files Build Phase` Menu is disabled in my XCode.

Comment: @MidhunMP Did you select the correct target, and click on "Build Phases" tab ?

Comment: @MidhunMP And the "Build Phases" tab is correctly selected ? Because "Add Build Phase" submenus are enabled only if you have selected the correct tab.

Comment: @MidhunMP In Xcode 4, the option is in Editor->Add Build Phase. The Copy Files build phase then appears in the Project Navigator and you can add things to it by clicking the plus.

Comment: once in a while I forget this step. 1+ for this.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and this is how I have solved it,

For my case, custom Framework is in **Swift** and My project is in **Objective c**

Follow the following steps,

1. Go the Project Navigator
2. Select the **Targets**, go the **General** tab
3. Find **Embedded Binaries** drag the custom framework.  Find the flow
   in the below-mentioned image[image]
4. Check if the Framework is added to the **Linked Frameworks and
   Libraries** (ref the image)[image: List item]
5. NOTE: In my case it was added to *Linked Frameworks and Libraries*, go a head and **remove** it
6. Last step, find the flag **Always embed swift embedded libraries**in
   "Build settings" and turn it to "YES" (ref the image)

[image]

I hope this helps.