# Unable to run pServe due to psycopg2 error

Tags: python

I am not being able to run `pserve` due to following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I am on OSX 10.6

Comment: Did you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found)?

Comment: @RenaeLider It does not seem to helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

It try to load `libpq.5.dylib` from the symlink `libpq.5.dylib` but found not file, so you need to update it:

```bash
# TODO: get this from the error, after "Library not loaded:"
SYMLINK_PATH="libpq.5.dylib"

# TODO: find this in your machine. The version maybe different than mine
DESTINATION_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib"

sudo mv $SYMLINK_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH.old
sudo ln -s $DESTINATION_PATH $SYMLINK_PATH
```