# Archived App not working. Run from XCODE successful

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I have made an app with swift which is working when I run it from XCODE. However, when i try to archive it and run the .app, it will not start.

How can I check why the app is crashing/not starting? What can be the reasons?

This is what the console output if I enter the packe and start it from the folder Contents/MACOs

```
Mislavs-MBP:~ proslav$ /Users/proslav/Desktop/trackingCore.app/Contents/MacOS
/trackingCore ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SQLite.framework/Versions/A/SQLite
Referenced from: /Users/proslav/Desktop/trackingCore.app/Contents/MacOS   
/trackingCore
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout
```

running it from the terminal gives the following output

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/proslav
/Desktop/trackingCore.app.
```

I have added a framework https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift to access a SQLite database. That is the library that is not loaded although it exists in the .app

Comment: You could put some console printing stuff in and run it via the terminal to see what, if anything, is printing.

Comment: First, running an app using Xcode and running it after archiving are two different environments, development and production, I think. I used to have similar issues, but the reason behind may be different. Anyway, if you are using keychainwrapper stuff, that might be a cause. But, please provide more info before people can come up with ideas.

Comment: I added some more Information. I Understand the fact that they are two different enviroments. Yet I cannot tell why it is not working when I archive it.

Comment: Are you linking to SQLite?  http://i.imgur.com/qjvHqnE.png  And the framework you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In the copy files i was linking to resources instead of frameworks. It seemed to be no problem for run but it was for archving.

Comment: Here's a more detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30979099/1123556

Answer (score 1):

Anyone arriving here based on the title, note that Xcode OSx builds are broken now.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1884/_index.html

They recommend using command line tools;

```
$ productbuild --component Sample.app /Applications --sign “3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:" Sample.pkg

$ sudo installer -store -pkg Sample.pkg -target /
```