# 3rd party Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'

Tags: xcode7, cocoapods, pspdfkit

I am upgrading a framework to latest version. Earlier integration (>2 years old) had framework directly copied in the project; now getting cocoapod (0.39.0) to get framework integrated with project using xcode (7.2.1) and objective-c project.

Upon run, it generates following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/name.framework/name
Referenced from:

/Users/xyz_xyz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxxx/appname.app/appname
Reason: image not found
```

"Pod" xcode-project has correct reference and framework is present in corresponding folder

Found that nameFramework isn't linked (added) in any of the build phases. I am new to using cocoapods and not sure what changes would be necessary in Xcode build settings to make transition from directly-embedded framework to cocoapods based integration.

- how to get past "dyld: Library not loaded" error?
- What phase should I use to reference name.Framework during build as it's not getting generated?
- How to copy bundle resources from Pod to project? Dragging-n-drop  Pods/name/Resources/name.bundle prompts "copy item if needed" dialog. <- I don't think I need to do this when using cocoapods.

[update] Integration using cocoapods works fine when a sample or new project is used. It's something in the current project settings that's causing the issue.

Podfile:

```html
platform :ios, '8.0'

# use_framework for swift based pod integration. requires cocoapod 0.39.0
#use_frameworks!

pod 'GTMOAuth2'
pod 'Typhoon'

pod 'Alamofire'

# Issue with name
pod 'name', podspec:'https://customers.pspdfkit.com/cocoapods/.../latest.podspec'

target :ABC do
        pod '...', '~>1'
end

target :XYZ do
        pod '...', :path => 'submodules/...'
end
```

[Update]
 - Upgraded to CocoaPods 1.0.1 & modified the Podfile to uncomment use_frameworks!, and make other changes that are required for 0.39.0 to 1.0.1 migration. Here is the updated Podfile.

```html
platform :ios, '8.0'

# use_framework is required for dynamic links (swift) based pod integration.
use_frameworks!

target 'XYZ' do
    pod 'GTMOAuth2'

    pod 'Alamofire'

    pod 'name', podspec:'https://customers.name.com/cocoapods/.../latest.podspec'

    target :XYZ-A do
            pod 'XYZ-iOS-SDK', :path => 'submodules/xyz-ios-sdk'
    end
end
```

Fixed errors such as following by adding $(inherited) flag (where applicable)

- [!] The `XYZ-v2 [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in ...

Progress after above changes, Pods/Target Supported Files/XYZ-v2/ has Pods-XYZ-v2-frameworks.sh and resources.sh; earlier frameworks.sh was missing. Following is partial content of the framworks.sh, and it does contain copy instructions.

```html
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
  install_framework "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/GTMOAuth2/GTMOAuth2.framework"
  install_framework "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.framework"
  install_framework "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/GoogleAPIClient/GoogleAPIClient.framework"
  install_framework "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/Mantle/Mantle.framework"
  install_framework "${PODS_ROOT}/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKit.framework"
  install_framework "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/SSKeychain/SSKeychain.framework"
fi

// and for "Release" & "Distribution" as well..
```

Now I am trying to resolve compile errors upon build, which are related to static vs dynamic library includes.

- /path../Pods/SSKeychain/Sources/SSKeychain.h:65:1: Duplicate interface definition for class ‘SSKeychain'

[Updated] Posted a new question: [CocoaPods 1.0.1 Redefinition of 'XYZ', Redefinition of enumerator 'ABC', Duplicate interface definition for 'MNO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003915/cocoapods-1-0-1-redefinition-of-xyz-redefinition-of-enumerator-abc-duplica)

Related:

- [OS X Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found/37275878#37275878)
- Seems relevant: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `use_frameworks!` (it's currently commented out). PSPDFKit is a dynamic framework, so you need to enable this option.

Also try it with the newest Xcode and CocoaPods >= 1.0.0. Older versions might not work correctly.

You can find more information about PSPDFKit integration via CocoaPods here: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/getting-started/using-cocoapods

If all of this doesn't help you can reach the PSPDFKit developers directly at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request

Comment: Last evening, I did make similar changes; today updated the question with results based on your suggestions. Now fighting the new compiler errors. Thanks Julian.

Comment: Now, issues I am trying to solve aren't specific to PSPDFKit. It started with upgrading PSPDFKit, but mutated into something else. Perhaps I should edit the original question or post of new one with new issues specifically.

Comment: Added a new post with specific question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003915/cocoapods-1-0-1-redefinition-of-xyz-redefinition-of-enumerator-abc-duplica

Answer (score 0):

same issue on dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/TwilioAccessManager.framework/TwilioAccessManager
Reason: image not found

I had the same problem, this fixed it for me.I Changed Framework status required to optional .