# g++ compiling not recognizing '*' for matrix multiplication using armadillo library

Tags: c++, g++, armadillo

I am running into an error when compiling the following C++ code:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

int main() {
mat A;
mat B;
mat C;

// Populating the matrices with random numbers
A.randu(3,3);
B.randu(3,3);

// Matrix multiplication
C = A * B;

cout << "Mutliplying matrices A and B:" << endl;
cout << "A * B = " << C << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Here is my error when compiling with g++:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>    "_wrapper_dgemm_", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*, > int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double > const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*) in   >armadillo_playground-aa3649.o
> ```
>
> "_wrapper_dgemv_", referenced from:
>
> ```
>  void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, >double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, >double const*, double*, int const*) in armadillo_playground-aa3649.o
> ```
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see >invocation)

When I replace the matrix multiplication '*' with '+', '%', etc. the code compiles without complaint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the definition for the `*` operator is in the source file, and you're not linking the library in?

Comment: Oops, I was unaware of linking in the library. However, now I am running into the following error: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/arpack/libexec/lib/libarpack.2.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Maybe this is of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found

Comment: Looks like I am going to need a bit more digging; this is my first time using an external library, and I am not familiar with Xcode. The project I am working on is linking C++ into some R code for a machine learning task.

Comment: @ToddYoung - why not use just [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html) where this is all taken care of for you?

Comment: As currently posed the question is all about Armadillo and has nothing to do with use from R (via Rcpp) so I am removing the Rcpp tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a simple *linker* error which you can overcome by correctly building. Exactly what you need will depend on your system / OS (and is all documented) but on my Linux box this works:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ g++ -o arma arma.cpp -larmadillo 
edd@max:/tmp$ ./arma 
Mutliplying matrices A and B:
A * B =    1.0574   1.0356   1.5178
   1.1368   1.3434   1.4919
   0.7028   0.6516   1.0423

edd@max:/tmp$
```

Here `arma.cpp` is the file containing your example. Linking with just the `libarmadillo.so` library is sufficient as it is linked to LAPACK and BLAS libraries.  Other OSs may have different use patterns.

Comment: Thanks for input, Dirk. I am a beginner and am still having some issues. I kept getting stuck so I decided to uninstall and reinstall using homebrew. after brew install I changed into the directory '/usr/local/Cellar/armadillo/7.200.2' and tried running CMake as directed in the readme.txt. I am now running into this error: directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @ToddYoung - after installing Armadillo using Homebrew, you don't need to install it again with CMake.