# All WatchKit apps are crashing on startup on real devices - 'warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data'

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

All the WatchKit apps I'm building is working fully in the simulator, but whenever I'm trying to install the app on my real device (Apple Watch Series 1), the app crashes before the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is being called in the `ExtensionDelegate.swift`.

The crash occurs for all the new and existing Apple WatchKit apps I'm trying to run on the real device `Apple Watch Series 1` 5.3.1

This is the output I get from the console:

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

[image: Xcode console output]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any APIs that require permission?

Comment: Nope that's not the case.

Comment: have you tried the answers from this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027601/dyld-abort-with-payload-with-no-error-message

Comment: Yup I have tried it, still not working..

Answer (score 0):

Updating the watchOS version from 5.3.1 to 6.0.1 resolved the issue for me. XCode version is 11.1

Before I tried many other suggestions without any success:
- Clean build
- Restart of XCode, MAC, iPhone, Watch
- Remove and reinstall of my watch app
- Re-pairing the watch with my iPhone
- Playing with the settings of Embedded binaries