# Flutter won't run on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

Flutter does not work on my iOS device (iPhone X).

When I run using 'flutter run' it keeps compiling ( up to 'Installing and launching...' ) and opening a blank app for like a second.

When I run my app using Xcode, it opens a blank app, and I receive this error message:

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x1013975dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x1013975e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1013975e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x101397600               ; <+36>     #Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
0x1013975e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1013975ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x1013975f0 <+20>: bl     0x101395be8               ; cerror_nocancel
0x1013975f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x1013975f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x1013975fc <+32>: ret    
0x101397600 <+36>: ret
```

and:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Flutter.framework/Flutter
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Runner
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/57467581-3BC4-4097-AA4A-717D2AA9BF93/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: stat() failed with errno=1
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76,
locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

iOS version: 13.3.1

MacOs version: Catalina 10.15.3

Important notice: It works on my iPad or on a Simulator ( iOS and Android ).

Comment: It looks highly related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027601/dyld-abort-with-payload-with-no-error-message Have you tried the fix ?

Comment: Well, it 's not really related, he has another error, and the answer did not fixed my issue.

Comment: did you fixed this problem? and how did you fixed it? @DariusBuhai I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a flutter issue, it has to do with apple latest ios 13.3.1.
It also reproduces by creating a new Xcode project and just adding a framework target, which automatically gets embedded and linked in the app target.

More details about the issue: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49504