# ionic 4 ios: libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

When trying to get the ionic 4 app launched on the device iphone7 from the ionic cli `$ ionic cordova run ios` it all compiles fine and then when it launches it opens and closes immediately. When I try to compile and launch it does the same, however, what's different is that once it launches and is on the spash-screen it freezes and in the xcode it zooms in, on what looks like a spot in memory.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
0x1b8228928 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1b822892c <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1b8228930 <+8>:  b.lo   0x1b822894c               ; <+36>  Thread 5 signal: SIGABRT
    0x1b8228934 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1b8228938 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1b822893c <+20>: bl     0x1b8208f64               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1b8228940 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1b8228944 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1b8228948 <+32>: ret    
    0x1b822894c <+36>: ret
```

I haven't found any information about this online involving ionic 4 and cordova. Hopefully someone has had this issue before and knows where they could point me in the right direction.

I have made sure everything is up to date, removed platform, add again, remove node modules, fresh build, still the same issue.

Comment: did you try to find a solution in this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027601/dyld-abort-with-payload-with-no-error-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly the error wasn't any of that. we eventually found out that it was compiling and running fine on some ios and other not. After some research and digging through bad docs, we found that below 13.x you don't need to include the Bluetooth for the permissions, so removing the permission request for Bluetooth on the ios.xml and plugin.xml fixed the issue. ( We are not using Bluetooth in the app so it's fine)

Comment: Can you please tell where is the ios.xml and plugin.xml? I have the same issue, but I could not find these files in my ios project.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same error before but not in ionic framework. The error is the same and maybe these steps can solve your error too:

- Go to "Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Diagnostics" and disable
  "Thread Sanitizer" and "Guard Malloc"
- "Product > Clean Build Folder"
- Add camera and library usage descriptions to your info.plist (if
  neccessary)
- Rebuild project
- Run