# Xcode 12 simulator crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode12

I'm getting weird crash in Xcode 12 simulator with signal SIGABRT right after launch. it is happening on released version of Xcode 12.0 and Xcode 12.0.1
I have tried with newest beta 12.2.

App is working fine on device.

I can not trace much due to less log. following is stack.

**Thread 1**

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x1194b0ed4 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
0x1194b0ed9 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x1194b0edc <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1194b0ede <+10>: jae    0x1194b0ee8               ; <+20>
0x1194b0ee0 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x1194b0ee3 <+15>: jmp    0x1194af408               ; cerror_nocancel
0x1194b0ee8 <+20>: retq   
0x1194b0ee9 <+21>: nop    
0x1194b0eea <+22>: nop    
0x1194b0eeb <+23>: nop
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT After Adding exception break point, getting following console output

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libnfshared.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreNFC.framework/CoreNFC
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/lib/libnfshared.dylib: mach-o, but not built for platform iOS-sim
```

In my project i'm not using CoreNFC. it is not linked and not being used by pods, this i've already checked

Comment: This of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027601/dyld-abort-with-payload-with-no-error-message

Comment: Yes
thread sanitizer if OFF
 Malloc is OFF
Zombies are OFF
not using custom framework
only Pods and some system frameworks (adSupport, CoreTelephony and iAd)

Comment: You have entitlements for all these (ad, telephone..)? Also, are you using any arguments to run it?

Comment: most of them are for firebase, and no special argument for them

Comment: Did you enable exception breakpoints in Xcode?

Comment: You can try the usual - delete ```~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Derived data```. Also make a backup of ```Developer``` and delete e.g. the ```Caches``` in Core Simulators and anything that looks remotely temporary and give it another go.

Comment: @koen i have updated my question after adding breakpoint exception

Comment: @ArslanAsim Looks like a bug in iOS 14: https://openradar.appspot.com/FB8699389

Comment: imo just in case try pod update

Answer (score 4):

> My solution: Manually copied libnfshared.dylib from Xcode 12 beta 6 to:
> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/

This works for me.

If you want to avoid the hassle of downloading 11.25GB Xcode 12.2 beta for a single file. I have the file to share.

You may execute the following command to download and place it inside the Xcode package:

```sh
sudo curl https://storage.googleapis.com/mobile-simulator-build/libnfshared.dylib -o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libnfshared.dylib
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where the simulator for `iOS14` would crash right after launch. The older iOS simulators and deploying to a device with `iOS14` worked fine.

My solution:
Manually copied `libnfshared.dylib` from Xcode 12 beta 6 to:

> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/

as it appears this file is missing in release version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

delete "VALID_ARCHS" from Target/App/Build Settings.

If you have Bitrise builds than I suggest adding: arm64 x86_64 to it.
Because for some reason Bitrise currently will crash if "VALID_ARCHS" is removed.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issues gets solved with

> Xcode-12.2 beta 2. Released on September 29, 2020.

waiting for stable version to confirm if things work as expected as working in beta.