# Xcode reports errors dyld abort with payload and libdyld.dylib start

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, macos-catalina

Run opencv test program in xcode

```
#include <iostream>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat img;
    img=imread("file:///Library/Desktop%20Pictures/Mojave%20Night.jpg");
    if (img.empty()) {
        cout<<"wrong"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("test", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

It shows that the operation is successful, but there is no result, and an error is reported

```
libdyld.dylib`start:
```

and

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
```

I'm a novice. I've tried a lot of experience sharing, but I still can't solve it. I really don't know why. Please answer and thank you!

Comment: See if any answer from this thread solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027601/dyld-abort-with-payload-with-no-error-message