# OS X Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found' for command-line

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, xcode8

I have build a framework and wanted to use it in another project but I can't

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1

It's a Command-line project so there is no "Embedded binaries" section in the "General" tab as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found).

I have added it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and also in "Copy Files" like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25059712/4859791). But didn't work.

[image]

I didn't understand how to set "Runpath Search Paths" like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275878/7381830).

My project is at:

```
~/Documents->Xcode->project_folder
```

My output is at:

```
~/Documents->Outputs
```

So how can I set "Runpath Search Paths" or is there any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: Any luck here? I have a similar issue and this was near the top of my search!

Comment: @Smashman we can't use our custom made frameworks in a command-line because in a GUI app, the frameworks are copied and packed inside `.app` which is not possible in command-line. So, I just added the source code files to the command-line project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use our custom made frameworks in a command-line.

Because in a GUI app, the frameworks are copied and packed inside `.app`, which is not possible in command-line.

So, I just added the source code files to the command-line project.