# image not found error when adding frameworks in xcode 9.1

Tags: xcode, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using module react-native-ble-plx for blutooth.

But when link the module and adding frameworks and when running in iOS it throws me error like

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/stellent/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E50C000-22C0-4519-BEAD-6092EA083132/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B2064C92-B8CC-43EC-B69D-E8B2FB21893B/bluetoothsample.app/Frameworks/RxBluetoothKit.framework/RxBluetoothKit
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

This happens in xocde 9.1 in xcode 8 its working fine.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found

Comment: thanks for me your response  i followed this link but i wont get any out put from this link