# `xcodebuild` not working from terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild, macos-high-sierra, xcode-command-line-tools

After I used migration assistant to migrate data from my old mac to a new one I can no longer use Xcode command line tools. Whenever I run any `xcodebuild` command in terminal (even `xcodebuild` with no parameters) I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

When I run `which xcodebuild` I get `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`.

When I run `xcode-select -p` I get `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Strangely, if I go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` and call `./xcodebuild` I **do not** get the error above.

Here is what I tried:

1. Installing command line tools using `xcode-select --install`.
2. Uninstalling command line tools located in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`.
3. Performing `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`.
4. Performing `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`.

None of these resolves my problem.

I am running Xcode 9.4.1 and macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

## UPDATE 1

I tried following [this guide](https://www.client9.com/uninstall-xcode-on-macos-sierra/) to uninstall Xcode and all command line build tools completely. The strange thing is, once I followed all the steps, running `xcodebuild` command produced the same result as before. And `xcodebuild` was still located in `/usr/bin`.

## UPDATE 2

If I install command line tools using `xcode-select --install` and go to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin` running `xcodebuild` from that location **does produce** the same error. So, running `xcodebuild` which comes pre-installed with Xcode produces no error, but the one from the command line tools does produce the error. It is puzzling and also suggests that when I try to remove all command line tools, the ones left in my `/usr/bin` are the ones which do not come with Xcode.

I tried deleting them, but I am unsuccessful even with the `sudo` command.

## UPDATE 3

I've found a workaround. To ensure that `xcodebuild` command uses the tool located in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` rather than the one located in `/usr/bin`, I added the following line to my `.bash_profile`:

`export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"`

This approach works, but my question remains. I do not understand why I had this problem in the first place. I have double checked - my `PATH` does not contain `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` on my old Mac and everything works just fine there.

Looks like for some reason, `xcodebuild` located in `/usr/bin` got corrupted and couldn't get updated in any way.

Comment: Error is not related to build command. xcodebuild not getting framework path correctly. Similar issue may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found

Comment: @VishalRajole I doubt that this issue is related to the framework path. When I run xcodebuild with no arguments in an empty folder it shouldn't try to build anything.

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk have you found any solution? I got this issue as well after upgrading my Macbook and migrating all the data onto it

Comment: Весьма забавно, что одна и та же проблема (и, кажется, редкая) появилась в одно и то же время у людей со схожими именами :)