# Delphi/ios: when linking a dynamic library app crash immediately with error "image not found"

Tags: ios, delphi, bitcode

I try to use in my app the library https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC. So I Download it from cocoapods (https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/0d72a13625d8f3e5/GoogleWebRTC-1.1.25331.tar.gz) and unpack it. I have :

```
c:\sdk\WebRTC.framework
  c:\sdk\WebRTC.framework\Headers
  c:\sdk\WebRTC.framework\Modules
  c:\sdk\WebRTC.framework\WebRTC
```

In the search path I add `c:\sdk\WebRTC.framework`. Now in my unit I add this line:

```
procedure StubProc1; cdecl; external 'WebRTC' name 'OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPeerConnectionFactory';
```

The compilation and linking work OK, but when I deploy the App, the app crash immediately. When I look the log I can see:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: 
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC | Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A2C3A7DA-D35E-4649-AEA0-9AB518E48971/ALLiveVideoChatClient.app/ALLiveVideoChatClient
>   | Reason: **image not found** Triggered by Thread:  0

Any idea why I have this "image not found" error?

If it's matter, https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC say:

> This pod contains the WebRTC iOS SDK in binary form. It is a dynamic
>   library that contains the armv7, arm64 and x86_64 slices. **Bitcode is
>   not supported**. Our currently provided API’s are Objective C only.

Comment: In Xcode there's an option to specify the framework as "embedded": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found. What that translates to (presumably as a linker option), I can't seem to find: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ld/

Comment: @DaveNottage: thanks, me too I can't find any option like this. I try to manually deploy the WebRTC file in .\Frameworks\WebRTC.framework folder but I can't deploy the app, I always have error e8000067 :(

Comment: Do you deploy your library with the project?

Comment: @GolezTrol: I try to deploy it in .\Frameworks\WebRTC.framework (I hope it's the good folder to deploy it, I not sure) but I always receive error e8000067 :( also I don't understand with architecture to deploy, I have only one library containing the armv7, arm64 and x86_64 slices so I don't know how it's work

Comment: Judging by the error message, it should be in `WebRTC.framework/WebRTC`, so not in a `frameworks` sub folder. But then again, I never deployed a Delphi app to ios, so I'm not 100% sure.