# App crash - AuthenticationServices Library not loaded

Tags: swift, appauth

I'm trying to use AppAuth-iOS dev-logout branch and I tested on simulator 10.3.1.
When I try to run the code I get this crash:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AuthenticationServices.framework/AuthenticationServices
>   Reason: image not found

AuthenticationServices only appeared in iOS 12.0+, so this may be the cause of the crash.

Link to github issue: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/350

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can mark the `AuthenticationServices.framework` as Optional in the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thats under: my project > my target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries. Click the "+" to add the frame work, then change its status to Optional.

Comment: This was similar to what I was experiencing.  I was developing in flutter for iOS and Android. The error was solved using xCode as that specific framework was not being embedded

Answer (score 0):

You can add the library/framework to the `Embedded libraries and frameworks` section. Also have a look at [OS X Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is as dumb as I am:

I was running a newer version of the Xcode Beta than my device's iOS version. Updating my device fixed this is