# Library not loaded on application after adding framework

Tags: swift, xcode

I have 2 targets, my actual application and my Framework (that has some screens and logic inside of it)

[image]

As ive seen done in many tutorials, i'm initialising the framework screens by calling the first screen in the framework:

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: HomeViewController.self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: frameworkBundle)
        window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Everything builds up fine, but before the actualy application can load up i get an error saying :

```
Library not loaded
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
target 'TriageFramework' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 2.5'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'SwiftKeychainWrapper'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'

  target 'Virtual First' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end


end
```

Here is the full error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/PhoneNumberKit.framework/PhoneNumberKit
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DC8D338-6DD7-4CCA-8FD5-804DD00FE015/Virtual First.app/Virtual First
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DC8D338-6DD7-4CCA-8FD5-804DD00FE015/Virtual First.app/Frameworks/PhoneNumberKit.framework/PhoneNumberKit: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DC8D338-6DD7-4CCA-8FD5-804DD00FE015/Virtual First.app/Frameworks/PhoneNumberKit.framework/PhoneNumberKit: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9DC8D338-6DD7-4CCA-8FD5-804DD00FE015/Virtual First.app/Frameworks/PhoneNumberKit.framework/PhoneNumberKit: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found)

Comment: @Sateesh it's not, i looked into that first prior opening this question, and i have it just in the same settings as in the answer in that post,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete derive data and clean the project. Run now.

Comment: Yes In project's embedded binaries.

Comment: I cannot add it to my "Project" embedded libraries as it say: "PhoneNumberKit.framework: No such file or directory"

Comment: You can click on plus icon and search for your framework and add it.

Comment: I Did that and then it say: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok then you can drag and drop directly from location where your framework exist.

Comment: OK, did it, dragged the file, i still get the same error on build time on the device

Comment: deleting Derived data fixed the problem no need to copy binary's, just edit your answer and i'll give u the correct answer

Comment: Fixed it i get a different Error now i'll edit the original Question

Comment: I think yo should ask new question for that.

Comment: it's exatctly the same problem, it's just that the error i get is a bit bit different, should i ask a new one for that ?

Comment: i updated the question you can look, it's almost the same. look in my full log

Comment: Yes you should ask new question and don't edit your question because as you conformed that above solution worked for your problem , it can help others.