# How can i add pod(third party framework) into my custom cocoa touch framework?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a new Cocoa Touch Framework (MyFramework.framework), which will have a dependency on Alamofire. This framework will be written in Swift. As a test I started a new Cocoa Touch Framework project:

```
File > New > Project > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Framework
```

Then, in the terminal I performed:

```
pod init
```

under this projects directory. In the newly created Podfile I added the following:

// Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

// Uncomment this line if you're using Swift

use_frameworks!

```
pod 'Alamofire'
```

Once again, in the Terminal I performed:

pod install

and started coding away.

Everything seemed well and good till I used the MyFramework.framework Product in a Single View Project. When I attempt to run the project I get the following issue:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/testfm.framework/MyFramework
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D4456F6A-2EBB-4AF9-B974-37A66E42D374/test.app/test
```

Reason: image not found

please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: plz check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found

Comment: you make pod spec and then pod install

Comment: Did you import the Alamofire in the file?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia - yes, i have already import alamofire in the file.

Comment: Have you Embed the framework ? As @Vishnu said

Answer (score 3):

Try to Embed MyFramework.framework into Build phase -> Embed Framework. like @Vishnu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Following Steps May be Help.

- Delete the current `.xcworkspace` File
- Open the `.xcodeproj` Just remove the pod from the project
- Delete the current Pod file From the project and Clean the Project
- Now go to file `File -> New -> File -> Select the Empty File.` save File with `Podfile` name. (Must save the Project in main Directory).
- Open the `Terminal` and Drag and drop `Podfile`and install the pod again.
- now close the `.xcodeproj`and open the `.xcworkspace` file.

Hope this Works.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you must have found the answer by now. For anyone else, make sure your custom framework setting is configured to "Embed & Sign" (As in image attached)

Then run your app.

[image]