# ImportError: Library not loaded for f2py

Tags: python, macos, gfortran, f2py

I'm using `f2py` to compile a Fortran subroutine to be called in a Python script.

I have compiled the Fortran source on Mac #1, running `Mojave 10.14`.  I compiled it using:

```sh
f2py -c -m <ModuleName> <SourceName.f90>
```

This works. I get a `.so` file that I can them import in Python using:

```py
import <ModuleName> as m
```

The issue comes when I try to run it on another Mac.

On Mac #2, also running Mojave 10.14, when I try and use the pre-compiled module:

```py
>>> import <ModuleName> as m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Stats_Wizard.py", line 20, in <module>
    import <ModuleName> as sf
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/<ModuleName>.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/<ModuleName>.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I checked the hash of the `.so` files on each computer and they matched. Which means there's an issue with using the `.so` between computers.

Is there a reason why I would not be able to use the same pre-compiled version on each computer?

EDIT: A point of note that differs between Mac #1 and Mac #2: Mac #1 has `gfortran` installed, Mac #2 does NOT. However, I feel that this should not make a difference because the module is already compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error (which I believe is self explanatory): `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/libgfortran.5.dylib ... Reason: image not found`, and the edit at the end of your question already include an (unwanted) answer :)

Your module (*ModuleName.so*) only contains your code and is using "stuff" from *libgfortran.dylib* which contains the *Fortran* core (or backend, if you will). 
When your module was built, it was linked to *libgfortran.dylib*, and as a consequence, **it needs that at runtime** (when it's loaded). To test that, try `otool -L ModuleName.so`.

So, *libgfortran.dylib* needs to be present on any machine (at the specified location) where your module is imported. Since I'm not an *OSX* user, here are some (theoretical) approaches to make that happen:

- Install the package that contains it. [[GNU.GCC]: gfortran installer for Mac OS X](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS) and other *URL*s mention something about installing *GCC*. But that seems a too big of an overhead, I wonder if there isn't some lightweight package that contains it too, and install that on the target machines
- Distribute the file yourself (note that this also applies to any other "special" *.dylib*s that it depends on). Copy it manually when you install your module. This is a workaround, don't know how feasible would this be from a licensing perspective, plus you also need *sudo*
- Build your module against a **static** *libgfortran* version. Again, I don't know if there is such a thing (or whether you'd have to build it manually, which I assume that would generate a huge amount of headaches - I built *GCC* (without *Fortran*, I think) on *OSX*, and it took me a couple of days (and lot of research) to get it done)

Comment: Ah, OK. So it's the problem that I was really hoping wasn't the problem. Thanks for your help. I ended up just installing gcc on Mac #2, and the problem is gone.

Comment: Apparently yes, at least according to my (limited) knowledge :(

Comment: I fixed it by doing `brew install gfortran`. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added directory of your built file to your python path. For checking if this is really the case try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"dir_parh/to/your/.so/file")
import lib_name
```

Comment: Thank you. I am importing the module from the same directory. I can import a different file from the same directory fine.

Comment: I stumbled on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found . Have you tried this? I don't have any experience on Mac OS so I can't really tell what's it about, just went for `image not found`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we solved the problem above. Turns out that it needs a certain `.dylib` file installed in a certain place.