# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am just trying to install mapBox in my project, and I'm getting this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/digitalgravity/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D6A86A86-478C-4988-9BFF-1A0DA6B05566/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/049C7FB8-4B79-4428-8AF7-6D9D1FF2846B/ADFD.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
>   Reason: image not found

Comment: Please check this:https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-ios/issues/131

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you did not add Mapbox framework to Framework, Libraries and Embedded Content correctly or your Pods were not linked properly (depending on react-native version you are using)

 This was asked and answered already so check [OS X Framework Library not loaded: 'Image not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993752/os-x-framework-library-not-loaded-image-not-found)