# iOS Framework only builds when running on a device

Tags: ios, xcode6

My Xcode project builds and runs on a device but it does not build against the simulator. I am using a custom Framework in my project. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774768/xcode-6-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-when-building-for-ios-simul) post seems to indicate that when you build a Framework to be included in another project you can only build it for the simulator or a device, but not both. Is this the case?

I am using Xcode 6.3.1

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you can only build for one platform at a time, but the answer in your link explains how to use a script to build a binary that contains the framework for both platforms.