# Xcode 7.3.1 - Missing required architecture i386 in .a file for iPad simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

I am trying to build/run my app for iPad simulator and i see below error on Xcode 7.3.1.

> error :- missing required architecture i386

However the same runs fine if I choose iPhone simulator, iPad device. What could be the problem and fix?

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774768/xcode-6-error-missing-required-architecture-i386-when-building-for-ios-simul

Comment: Yes i have checked this link, but i still see my issue on simulator.

Comment: Its been a long time. If you have found the solution please post your answer here. I have same problem.