# Library Load with Google Calendar API - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

> dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/GTL.framework/GTL
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2EE31349-7221-47AF-83E7-7B172F5ED6AD/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found

I've tried adding `GTL.framework` to **Embedded Binaries** but this didn't help. Any idea what might be wrong. I created a workspace and followed the directions exactly as given in the tutorial:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios

It's working fine on the simulator but gives me the above error when I try to run it on my device. Any ideas?

I'm running Xcode 7.2.1 and iOS 9.2

**Edit**

I've tried changing the installation path of the `GTLiOSCore` to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` but this doesn't fix anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["image not found" Error while using Custom FrameWork](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092886/image-not-found-error-while-using-custom-framework)

Comment: @EricKoleda Hi Eric, I tried the solution in that question but I still receive the error. Any other suggestions? Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry, that's my best guess. I'm still fairly new to iOS development.

Comment: @EricKoleda No worries, thanks. If you know anyone at Google who's worked on this API and could refer me, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded

Comment: on this read all answers...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib

Comment: @Anilsolanki can you point to which of those answers you think might help? For example, I don't think there's any Swift code in Google's library...

Answer (score 4):

In `GTLiOSCore` target go to **Build Settings** and change **Installation Directory** to: `@executable_path/Frameworks`

You can also verify that your main project's **Runpath Search Paths** property contain `@executable_path/Frameworks`.

I've tried several other combinations, but for some reason The Dynamic Link Editor(dyld) is unable to find GTL.framework when the installation path contains `/../`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that your framework has been built for all architectures and not just the simulator?

[Sample Build Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7fPD.png)

If that doesn't work you may need to create an aggregate target which includes target frameworks for both Simulator and devices.

See this link: [Create iOS Universal Framework](https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c#.vhqjo8296)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my own problem by changing **Mach-O Type** from **Dynamic Library** to **Static Library** in the `Build Settings` for `GTLiOSCore` (NOT the `Build Settings` for your app!).

[image]