# Xcode11 dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: image not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I am using Xcode11

I am getting following error, when I try to use a framework in a SampleAppSwift project:

**dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/VoiceSampler.framework/VoiceSampler**

**Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECB8715–2964–47B6–9F75–056F32846019/SampleAppSwift.app/SampleAppSwift**

**Reason: image not found**

In the SampleAppSwift project, under Build Settings, I tried setting 'Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries' to YES. That did not help.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: In the SampleAppSwift project, under Build Settings, I tried setting 'Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries' to YES. That did not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["image not found" Error while using Custom FrameWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092886/image-not-found-error-while-using-custom-framework)

Comment: At reviewers voting to close this question, the possible duplicate, does not answer this question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had same problem. You should add a Copy File phase in your Build Phases as follows:

Under Build Phases, click on `+` icon to add new phase, and select `New Copy Files Phase`.

Drag the newly created Copy Files phase above `Compile Sources` phase

In the new Copy Files phase, select `Frameworks` for `Destination` drop down.

Leave `subpath` blank. Let be default `Copy only when installing`.

Under the table, click '+' and then select your Framework, i.e. VoiceSampler.framework

Make sure `Code Sign on Copy` is checked (ticked).

Do a clean build.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Not sure why Xcode11 needs to add Frameworks this way.

Comment: it's not xcode 11 only, since long time it is there - https://stackoverflow.com/q/20092886/3145189

Comment: Worked for me also. Thanks

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks - I would never have quickly resolved this.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

General->Frameworks, Library, and Embedded Content.
If it's "Do Not Embed", change to "Embed Without Signing".

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: You saved my life

Comment: In my case I go this to work but I had to select "Embed & Sign"

Answer (score 2):

There is another simpler solution which worked for me if you are using Cocoapods.

In your Podfile, add **use_frameworks!** after your Target line like this -

```
target 'YourAppName' do
  use_frameworks!
```

Basically it adds all your pods as a framework in your framework folder.

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I had an issue with the swift lib not loading properly.